# How do I dynamically instantiate hardware from a list of available modules in SystemVerilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hardware

I'm trying to program a popular space shoot-em-up for a class project, and have run into a problem with module instantiation. We currently have a module that encodes the motion of a projectile and have created an array of them to be "activated."

We want our ship to fire as many projectiles as the user wants, and the projectiles will simply appear from the gun barrel and travel up the screen.

This translates to a simple internal state machine for each projectile:

1. Halt:

   - If the user wants to fire a shot, activate this module
2. Init:

   - Set the projectile position to match the gun barrel. Set the projectile motion to be nonzero.
3. Move:

   - If our collision detection unit sees a collision (with enemy or wall), disable module and go to Halt
   - Else simply step the position by some predetermined amount of pixels

I've got the state machine programmed properly, but currently if the user fires a shot, the shot goes until the edge of the screen and another shot cannot be fired while it exists.

Ideally, I'd have some sort of dictionary that I could look into and find an "available" projectile module to activate, which the state machine updates when that module is available to be fired again.

So the process would look like:

1. User wants to fire a projectile
2. Something... finds an element in our projectile array that isn't enabled and enables it
3. Shot goes, and disallows that module from taking on another shot until the current one is destroyed.

One way that I can think to do this is to read off the "enabled" bits from out projectile array, which would be a one-hot encoding of which are currently firing:

```
0110 0011 - Projectiles 1, 2, 6, and 7 are in use
```

We then take those bits, perform... something... on them, and get the number 3, which corresponds to the index of the smallest available projectile module. The number 3 is output for the user-input state machine to index into our array of projectile modules, which would then be sent the "activate" signal.

Answer (score 1):

You can't dynamically instantiate hardware. You write Verilog/SystemVerilog to describe how hardware should be built. If you have functionality that needs to be active at different times, you need to either incorporate that into your state machine, or us multiplexers that select between different outputs.

Comment: Yeah I did mention this in the post. I'm instantiating 10 of these "projectiles", and just trying to figure out when one is being used so that the next one can be fired. So the hardware is instantiated, I just need to figure out when to use which instance. Does that make sense?

Comment: When your question title is very misleading. By my answer still applies. You need to incorporate your "available bits into your state machine. Without seeing any code, it is difficult to help you further.